# Using debug symbols of an older exe for a newer exe

Tags: debugging-symbols

Sorry for the question if anything is wrong, I'm new to StackOverflow. I have DWARF debug file of a C++ Mac program of version (i.e. 1.1). Is there any way to use this debug information in a newer version (like 1.5) of the same program? Seeing what has changed is enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

you probably can't use I as-is but there some possibilities:

1. apply symbols to the version 1.1 then use some binary diffing/porting tool to find the matching functions in the version 1.5.
2. if you don't have the old binary, just dump the symbols and use the information in the binary (strings etc.) to find the matching functions and rename them. the addresses will probably be close but likely won't match exactly.

Comment: An option : Open 1.1 in Ida pro and apply the symbols, save the idb. Open 1.5 in Ida pro and save the idb, then use binnavi to compare both idbs and rename functions that match.

Comment: Yes, that’s item 1 on my list